# Potting on annuals into one pot

Tags: containers, repotting, annuals

I've grown some annuals (e.g. sunflower and cosmos) and pricked out the seedlings into small pots (one per seedling). Once the roots started to show at the bottom, I potted them on to 3 plants per 9-inch diameter pot - as per photo - which are now in my conservatory.

Is this alright or could it cause any issues? The reason I've done it like this is because I don't have space inside for each plant to have its own pot. Once the nights have got a bit warmer I plan to then pot them on into individual larger pots outside and plant some in the ground.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Good luck, I think you'll need it. My experiences with transplanting sunflowers are that they don't particularly approve of being transplanted at all, and being disturbed from the pot where they will all be throughly intertwined might well kill them, but we'll see if anyone can offer a more hopeful view or mitigating technique.